# How to print multiple PDFs of graph controlled by dropdown list using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, print-to-pdf

I have an Excel worksheet which generates a combination chart to show trend data on 49 manufacturing work cells. The chart source data is based on cells which contain a large number of formulas (center of image below). I have built the worksheet so that the user selects a work cell from the dropdown list in A5, and the formulas and graph are all automatically updated. The source for the data validation of A5 is a column in a table found in another worksheet. I have set up this worksheet with a print area around the graph.

[image: Excel Sheet screenshot]

Right now, I can use the following code to loop through all of the graphs and print each onto a single page PDF:

```
Sub TestLoopMacro()

    Sheets("My Sheet").Select

    'SOURCE FOR TIMER CODE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    'Remember time when macro starts
    StartTime = Timer


    Dim Count As Integer

    For Count = 2 To 50
        Range("A5").Select
        Range("A5").Value = Worksheets("Cells Sheet").Range("E" & Count)

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "H:\Some Path\Test Exports\" & Worksheets("Cells Sheet").Range("B" & Count) & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            False
    Next Count

    'Determine how many seconds code took to run
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    'Notify user in seconds
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

I would like to be able to print the graphs for all 49 cells into a single PDF. This code successfully creates 49 PDFs with unique graphs.

Is there a way that they can be exported to the same PDF with VBA instead of merging them with Adobe/similar afterward? I have found posted questions about trying to do similar things, but they involved print areas being exported from multiple worksheets (as opposed to multiple instances of the same worksheet).

Comment: What have you tried so far? A FOR loop does sound like the right solution, so have you tried that yet?

Comment: I managed to get the loop working this morning. Question has been edited with my current state code. It successfully loops through all 49 cells and creates 49 PDFs with the correct names. But I would like them to all be in a single PDF instead of separate. (side note - the run time for the macro is about 150 seconds)

Comment: Look up tips for accelerating Excel macros. There's a few simple things (like disabling screen redraw) that can speed up macros by orders of magnitude. To create a single PDF, you'll want to capture the output from each step of the FOR loop not as a print job, but in a prior form, then after the FOR loop is complete, print the entire output.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat supports javascript, so you might be able to do the merge of the documents using acrobat's `Doc.insertPages` method.

( https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FDoc_methods.htm%23TOC_insertPagesbc-73&rhtocid=_6_1_8_23_1_72 )

Alternatively, you can `Shell.ShellExecute` an open-source command-line pdf tool.